# How does capistrano "run_locally" work with branches?

Tags: deployment, capistrano, compass-sass

I have a capistrano task that uses "run_locally" to compass compile/compress my css files and then upload them to the server.

Is it going to be smart and run that on the git branch that's getting deployed, or will it just run on the branch that I currently have in my working copy?

I'd want it to run on the branch that's getting deployed regardless of what I have checked locally. If it's not smart about this would I instead need to run_locally a `git checkout` on the branch that's getting deployed before running the compile command?

Answer (score 2):

It runs on you current local code. So it matters what code is checked out there. As you mentioned you can try to ensure that you run the version you are going to deploy.

Better would be to do the compilation work on the server.